# How to get a modified array with or without spread syntax in this case?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

How to simplify and improve the code below?

The code below works as expected if `myarr.length === 2`:

```
[...myarr[0].arrk.map(myfunc), ...myarr[1].arrk.map(myfunc), ...myarr[2].arrk.map(myfunc)]
```

How to modify the code above so that `myarr`array could be any length so that the code above works for any length, not just for 2?  It should be all, not 2.

P.S. I believe the solution

```
myarr.map(a => a.arrk.map(myfunc))
```

is too close to the correct answer, but not exactly: it returns `[Array(1), Array(2)]`, but not the elements.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try that with [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```
myarr.flatMap(({arrk}) => arrk.map(myfunc))
```

Or, if `.flatMap()` is not available in your environment, the same thing with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
myarr.reduce((acc, {arrk}) => (acc.push(...arrk.map(myfunc)), acc), [])
```

Comment: Or `myarr.map(x => x.arrk.map(myfunc)).reduce((a, x) => [...a, ...x])`

Comment: @jcalz:  I don't quite like the idea of re-creating accumulator array with spread syntax upon each iteration - it slows down the code unnecessarily

Comment: @jcalz : check out the latest edit of my `.reduce()`-based solution - it is even more compact (while still perfectly readable), but still fast, so there seem to be no point to use spread-based flattening

Comment: Sure, but `reduce()` is more suited to multiple immutable accumulators, not a single mutable one; it would be nice if there were a `mutableReduce()` (bad name but whatever) where the callback took a `void` return type so you aren't forced to use that comma operator to keep handing back the same accumulator over and over again.  If performance is an issue either way I'd say you have a bigger problem than accumulator style, though.

Comment: Yes, you can use `concat()` to generate a new array instead of using spreading, if you want

Comment: @jcalz : ahhh, you're right I'll rollback to previous edit to be consistent :)